# How can I get value from user for click function using if statement for a password generator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I'm very new to JavaScript so forgive me if the code is wrong. I have a problem getting a value from the user when the value is a number or letter.

If it is a number the function should execute, but if it is not a number it should display an alert telling the user to input a valid number.

Well, my application displays the alert when the user entry is both a letter and/or a number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using an if statement which will be shown in the code below under the Generate click function. 
Edited to include HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="password.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="password.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Password Generator</h1>
        <h2>Generate a strong password</h2>
        <label for="num">Number of characters:</label>
        <input type="text" id="num"><br>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="password" disabled><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="generate" value="Get Password">
        <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear"><br>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getRandomNumber = function(max) {
    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
      var random;
      if (!isNaN(max)) {
        random = Math.random(); //value >= 0.0 and < 1.0
        random = Math.floor(random * max); //value is an integer between 0 and max - 1
        random = random + 1; //value is an integer between 1 and max
      }
    }
    return random;
  };
  $("#generate").click(function() {
    $("#password").val(""); // clear previous entry        
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-+!@";
    var num;

    if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
      //If the user entry is valid, the function will execute and return password
      return num;

      //If user entry isn't a valid number, display alert
    } else if (isNaN(num)) {
      alert(" Please enter a valid number ");
    }
  }); // end click()

  $("#clear").click(function() {
    $("#num").val("");
    $("#password").val("");
    $("#num").focus();
  }); // end click()

  // set focus on initial load
  $("#num").focus();
}); // end ready()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide html part.

and when you click #generate, you didn't define the value of num variable.

Change this line and try again

```
var num= $("#num").val();
```

Comment: ANd he is not returning password but the number

Comment: Definitely worked. Forgot to take out the quotes! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should get the user input to a variable and validate that

```
var num = $("#password").val(""); // clear previous entry        

if (isNaN(num)) {
  return alert(" Please enter a valid number ");
}
else {

  if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
     return num;
  else
     // ..... return another error message here

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Only had to take out the quotes+